# trouble getting full page bootstrap carousel center and fitted

Tags: css, carousel

I am trying to get a full page bootstrap carousel to work. Currently the photos show up to the left and different sizes. I would like them to be centered and filled all with the same height. I am using the react bootstrap carousel package. I have looked all over. I added flex to my carousel item and it centered everything perfectly but broke the slider. css has never been my strong point so any help would be appreciated.

```
  <Carousel 
    prevIcon={prevIcon}
    nextIcon={nextIcon} 
    interval={null} 
    slide={false} 
    style={{
     width: '100%;',
    }}>
     {this.state.sliderPhotos.map (s => 
      <Carousel.Item 
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%'
        }}>             
        <img src={s.photo} className="landing-page-image" 
         style={{
            objectFit: 'cover',
            height: '300px !important',
            width: '100%'
           }}/>
            <Carousel.Caption>
            
            </Carousel.Caption>
        </Carousel.Item>
    )}
    </Carousel>
```

Comment: When you say the images are to be full height I take it to mean full height of the containing element - so it's possible some wide ones  may get cropped left and right sides. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @AHaworth yes that is correct